# QRScanner Assistance with Parse/Int Deferencing

Tags: java, android

Just trying to flatten out bugs..

1. Int can not be dereferenced (on the StartWith Line)
2. Cannot find symbol method parse(int)

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
       if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
           if (resultCode.Startswith("http://") || resultCode.startsWith("https://")) {
               Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, URI.parse(resultCode));
               startActivity(browserIntent);
           }
   ```

Comment: startWith is for String objects no for native integers

Comment: @diegoveloper What would be a good alternative to change that to in order to get it working? as I'm trying to make a QRCode Scanner see its http (or https) then automatically direct to a web browser.

Comment: Ok, let me help you. Which QR library are you using?

Comment: And how are you calling the QR library, put the code

Comment: @diegoveloper Sent to your twitter handle via private msg :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
                String value = barcode.displayValue;
                if (value.startsWith("http://") || value.startsWith("https://")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(value)); 
                    startActivity(i); 
                }
            } else 
               {
                   Log.e("your_tag","no value captured"); 
               }
        } else Log.e("your_tag","barcode error "); 
    } else super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```